# SwitchPreference not changing state after setting onPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: android, switchpreference

I have an activity which extends PreferenceActivity and i have a class which extends PreferenceFragment.

After I initiate the switchPreference variable (inside the Fragment) I set OnPreferenceChangeListener to it.
The problem is when I do set a listener I cant change the state of the switch button (it remain at the same position).
If I disable the statement where Im setting the listener the switch button works fine and also the state is saved.

I also have a wrapper class for the sharedPreferences which I want to save a data into it on switchpreference change.

Did anyone encounter such a weird behavior?

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I found the the "onPreferenceChange" function returned false and when I changed it to true it worked.

Thanks to all who was looking for answering me.